# Code to calculate the duedate

Tags: calculated-column, date

Problem is to get code, which calculates from invoice date due date. Payment term is 150 net days and due date should be always on 10th day.

I know only how to get it like in Excel. `print_date` is invoice date.

```
=IF( DAY(print_date+´180´)>10
     ,DATE( YEAR(print_date +´180´)
            ,MONTH(print_date +´180´)
            ,10)
    ,IF( DAY(print_date +´180´)<10
         ,EDATE(DATE( YEAR(print_date +´180´)
                      ,MONTH(print_date +´180´)
                      ,10)
                ,-1)
         ,( print_date +´180´)))
```

Would be very grateful, if somebody write how to get such due date.

Comment: Where are you trying to calculate this - in a client-side script, in a calculated column, in a custom feature? Think you need to be more specific. On what value is the calculation based (assuming another column with some date in it)?

Comment: In a client-side script

Comment: Can you share the code? You're not really giving the right amount of detail. Is this even Sharepoint related? Where is the value you want to calculate intended to go?

Answer (score 0):

There is no EDATE in SharePoint Formulas

See: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Those are the only Functions you can work with.

They all match with Excel, so you can start by simplifying your Formula in Excel

PS. Copy that site...
I left the Microsoft world and I payed for hosting till end 2017